# Alternatives to OAuth for Google Cloud BigQuery for server to server?

Tags: api, oauth, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I was looking into using BigQuery for some analytics. From what I can tell the only authentication method available is OAuth, which is definitely less than ideal for Server-to-server queries (3rd party servers, not part of GCP).

Having to request a token and cache it really isn't workable in a web application that handles a lot of traffic, since the token expires every hour, and when it does, I'll get a cache-slam situation where I might end up with thousands of requests all needing a new token at the same time.

Is there similar to how AWS handles API requests where you just need an API key and you can sign a request?

Answer (score 0):

Google BigQuery supports server-to-server authentication based on service-accounts. Google also provides [client libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) for many languages which makes authentication easy for both web apps and server applications.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) is very detailed guide on how to perform server to server authentication using services accounts.

In my personal opinion, managing local API keys is not a very good idea security-wise and it's hard to manage them (rotate, secure, backup etc). Even AWS [doesn't recommend](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html) using API keys and suggests switching to IAM roles.

Comment: Authenticating a service account still requires getting a token (that expires every hour). The client libraries all do OAuth logins that do the same. This will result in a problem when the token expires and a new one is needed. AWS' use of IAM still makes use of API keys (for each IAM user). If Google has something similar, I would love that. OAuth is really not well suited for web apps with heavy traffic.

Comment: afaik, there is no other way. Service-accounts are extremely cool, we use for our ingestor and works great, no problem with refreshing, automatically the libraries have dedicated methods for this.